# Should the Stack Overflow FAQ page list the reputation needed to use chat?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

I looked at [Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) and don't see in the list how many points are needed to be able to use a chat room.

I'm conversing with someone in comments, and I think that with 35 rep they can't chat with me, so the comments continue.

- [**Primary**] Should the rep needed to chat be listed in the FAQ?
- [*Secondary*] Should a high-rep user be able to invite a low-rep user to join a chat?

(The second bullet has been asked before, but I'll ask it again, even though the main thrust of my question is the first bullet.)

Comment: It's on the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat), 20 rep required.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't also be in the nearly exhaustive list on the FAQ page, or a more clear suggestion be made to check the Privileges page.

Comment: So it is...so obvious...should it also be on the rep page?

Comment: I would think it merits being listed there.

Comment: The help pages were redesigned. Now the reputation page only shows how you can gain or lose reputation. The list of what you can do with reputation is now (mostly) exclusively on the privileges page.